# activate Sepolia testnet on geth

Tags: javascript, ethereum

12.0 on windows to connect sepolia testnet.
and i got this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpWy9.png)

i ran this command:
geth --syncmode light --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin --authrpc.jwtsecret ./consensus/prysm/jwt.hex console

how can i connect the sepolia testnet(light syncmode) on geth successfully?

i just wanna check the account balance which i got test sepolia ether from the sepolia faucet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.